# Export CSV as portal user

Tags: salesforce

I have a salesforce I export to CSV using a URL like this https://tapp0.salesforce.com/00OT00000014APi?export=1&enc=UTF-8&xf=csv following this [blog post](http://sfdc-heretic.warped-minds.com/2006/04/10/progmatic-access-to-salesforcecom-reports/).

This works fine and is very fast when I run for a fully licenced user.
However when I try to call the same report export as a Gold Patner portal user I get an error **"Insufficient Privileges"**

I have marked the report as deployed.
Given all users access to the Report Folder
The user does have the correct sharing and profile rules setup to view the data in the report.

Going to just the report URL by itself works https://tapp0.salesforce.com/00OT00000014APi
It only fails when I try to export to CSV.

I DO reliase I am using an unsuported internal API call. But was wondering is there anyway portal users can export reports to CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem

You need to go to Salesforce > Setup  > Manage Users > Profiles
Then Click to Edit the  RS_PortalUser  profile
Click the checkbox next to   “Run Reports”  and “Export Reports”
Click save

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about through the UI, but this can be done through a SOQL query and portal users do have limited access to the API. Most, but not all, reports can be converted to SOQL queries to produce the same output.

For running your query, the easiest is probably to build a Visualforce page that is backed by an Apex controller that runs the query and outputs a CSV. Take a look at the `contentType` attribute on the [`apex:page`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_page.htm?SearchType=Stem) tag. You can set things like `application/vnd.ms-excel#contacts.xls` to automatically export a data table to Excel. I didn't try, but it probably works with CSV too -- worst case is that you open in Excel first and save as CSV.

Also, if you don't mind portal users having to leave Salesforce to get their CSV, you might want to try [Workbench](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Workbench), which is an app I built that allows for portal user login and helps you build the SOQL query for CSV export both through the SOAP and Bulk APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I tried this already and it take 6-8 minutes. Whereas the salesforce built-in report only takes 5 seconds. So due to its slowness this is not really a viable option